# Equation for two particle elastic collision, both having velocity and size, in arbitrarily high dimension

Tags: collision

Is there any theory about general particle elastic collision (both having velocity, different mass, and different size) in arbitrarily high dimension?

I was thinking about conservation of momentum and energy, but I kind of confused myself. Since given dimension `N`, there are `2N` unknowns, but `N+1` equations for momentum and energy separately.

Answer (score 2):

For an elastic collision one could always choose a coordinate system with one of the axes along the line connecting the centers-of-mass of the two bodies. The problem then becomes a one-dimensional one (provided, we can treat the objects as point-like in the collision.)

Not sure though what is meant by *partially elastic collision* here. Elastic collision means that energy and momentum are conserved - that the objects have different masses doesn't change the nature of the collision.

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo. It is supposed to be "particle"

Answer (score 0):

starting with   2 particle collision :
\begin{align*}
&m_1\,(\mathbf v_1-\mathbf u_1)=-\lambda_{12}\,\mathbf{\hat{r}}_{12}\\
&m_2\,(\mathbf v_2-\mathbf u_2)=+\lambda_{12}\,\mathbf{\hat{r}}_{12}\\
&\left[~\mathbf v_2-\mathbf v_1+\epsilon(\mathbf u_2-\mathbf u_1)~\right]\cdot \,\mathbf{\hat{r}}_{12}=0\\
&\text{with}\\
&\mathbf{\hat{r}}_{12}=\frac{\mathbf r_2-\mathbf r_1}{\parallel\mathbf r_2-\mathbf r_1\parallel}
\end{align*}
where $~\mathbf v_i~$ the velocity after the collision,  $~\mathbf u_i~$ the starting velocity and $~\epsilon~$ the restoration coefficient.
$~(\epsilon=1~$ elastic collision).

you obtain 5 equations for the 5 unknowns $~\mathbf v_1~,\mathbf v_2~,\lambda_{12}~$

writing the equations   with matrix notation $~\mathbf A\,\mathbf x=\mathbf b$
\begin{align*}
 &\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
    m_1\,\mathbf I_2 & 0\mathbf I_2 &+\mathbf{\hat{r}}_{12}^T \\
    0\mathbf I_2 & m_2\,\mathbf I_2 & -\mathbf{\hat{r}}_{12}^T \\
    -\mathbf{\hat{r}}_{12}^T & +\mathbf{\hat{r}}_{12}^T & 0 \\
  \end{bmatrix}}_{\mathbf A_{5\times 5}}
 \underbrace{ \begin{bmatrix}
    \mathbf v_1 \\
    \mathbf v_2 \\
    \lambda_{12} \\
  \end{bmatrix}}_{\mathbf x}=
  \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
    m_1\,\mathbf u_1 \\
    m_2\,\mathbf u_2 \\
    \epsilon\,\mathbf{\hat{r}}_{12}\cdot (\mathbf u_1-\mathbf u_2) \\
  \end{bmatrix}}_{\mathbf b}\tag 1
\end{align*}

you can adapt   equation (1) for collision between any two particle, for example three particle collision, the possible collision are between
particle 1 and 2, 1 and 3 and 2 and 3,for each pair  you have to  solve the matrix equation (1).

Comment: Wait, so you don't even need to use conservation of energy? I'm not sure about the last equation but this looks cool

Comment: The energy conservation is the third equation but only for elastic collision. If you add the first two equations you obtain the momentum conservation